# Repartition by size with dask not producing files with expected size

Tags: python, dask, partition

I would like to benefit dask `repartition` feature, but the requested size is not fulfilled, and smaller files are produced.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import dask.dataframe as dd

file = 'example.parquet'
file_res_dd = 'example_res'

# Generate a random df and write it down as an input data file.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(100000, 20)),columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'])
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, file, version='2.0')

# Read back with dask, repartition, and write it down.
dd_df = dd.read_parquet(file, engine='pyarrow')
dd_df = dd_df.repartition(partition_size='1MB')
dd_df.to_parquet(file_res_dd, engine='pyarrow')
```

With this example, I am expecting files with size about 1MB.
Input file that is written 1st is about 1,7MB, so I am expecting 2 files at most.
But in the `example_res` folder that is created, I get 9 files being ~270kB.

Why is that so?

Thanks for your help! Bests,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "partition size" is of the in-memory representation, and only an approximation.

Parquet offers various encoding and compression options that generally result in a file that is a good deal smaller - but how much smaller will depend greatly on the specific data in question.

Comment: ok, thanks @mdurant. Please can you confirm that each file written contains one partition? (meaning, the in-memory data total size is between 2 & 3MB, and when I repartition, I get then 3 partitions)  I would like to make sure I understand correctly. Said otherwise, how can I check the number of partitions?  Thanks for your help, bests!

Comment: Yes, that should be right, but the apportionment is only approximate. You can always check the dataframe `.npartitions` before calling a compute.